How do I use `Pick` or `Omit` on a union of records?
I have a type that is a union of different record types, all with the same keys but with different type restrictions on some of the keys for each record. I noticed when I use Pick or Omit on this type, I lose some of the typechecking.
Here's a contrived example:
type A = {
  type: 'a',
  content: 'a-content'
};

type B = {
  type: 'b',
  content: 'b-content'
}

type Full = {id: number} & (A|B);

// This is valid
const full: Full = {
  id: 1,
  type: 'a',
  content: 'a-content'
}

// This is correctly marked as a type error
const invalidFull: Full = {
  id: 1,
  type: 'a',
  content: 'b-content'
}

// This is not marked as a type error, even though the 'content' field doesn't match the 'type' field
const invalidFullPartial: Omit<Full, 'id'> = {
  type: 'a',
  content: 'b-content'
}

How would you set this up so that you can use Omit or Pick on the Full type, and still have typescript ensure that the types of type and content match?

Pick/Omit do not distribute across unions so you need to write your own distributive version if you want that behavior; see the linked questions and answers above.
